# find depth of water

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The bottom of an underground rectangular tank has an area of $12$ square feet and the depth of the tank is $10$ feet. A liquid is pumped into the empty tank at the constant rate of $30$ cubic feet per minute. After how many minutes will the depth of the liquid in the tank be $8$ feet?

so first volume of  rectangular  tank is $12*10=120$ cubic,now  if water is pumped  $30$ cubic feet per minute,then it takes $4$ minute    to fill tank,but what about  $8$  depth,in this case volume would be $12*8=96$,does it would be $96/30=3.2$ minute?

Comment: Yes:  you can use the proportion $ \ \frac{120 \ ft^3}{4  \ min.} = \frac{96 \ ft^3}{T  \ min.} \ . $  Note that you can do this **only** because the area of the tank remains a constant $ \ 12 \ \text{sq.ft.} \ $ over the _entire_ height of the tank.

Comment: thanks in advance ,you can simple post  as answer,let us increase your and my  reputation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes:  you can use the proportion $$ \ \frac{120 \ ft^3}{4  \ \text{min.} } = \frac{96 \ ft^3}{T  \ \text{min.} } \ . $$

Note that you can do this **only** because the area of the tank remains a constant $ \ 12 \ \text{sq.ft.} \ $ over the *entire* height of the tank.  This will mean that a constant rate of water volume change produces a constant rate of water *depth* change.

Comment: but for  simple GRE  question,it would not happen usually right

Comment: If the cross-sectional area of the tank were _not_ a rectangle, then the surface area of each "layer" of added water would not necessarily be the same, so equal changes in water volume would not cause equal changes in water depth.  (If the cross-section of the tank is, say, a trapezoid, it is still not too difficult to work out the relation between volume and depth changes.  For more complicated shapes, calculus becomes the tool to apply to the problem.)

Comment: right  but because  it is not so complicated  GRE geometry problem,it should not be  expected such kind of  puzzles